# Finding a key in a JSON object and giving it a value. (Javascript)

Tags: json, object, find

I have a multiple step form. To validate each step I thought it might be handy to create a JSON object, Where each key acts as a step with the right fields.

My object is not finished, but looks now like this:

```
let validationSteps = {
0: {
    location: null,
    duration: null,
    membershipType: null,
},
1: {
    fname: null,
}
```

};

I want to fill each item by using an event listener. For example, when you fill in your first name. It should trigger something that searches for `fname` in the object, and fills it. But I have no clue how to find the key, since it's already inside an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this data structure. You should use `Object.keys()` to do a for loop to find where is the key you are looking for.(It looks like an array but you use it like a json)

```
function setValue(json,key,value){
    // for loop to check all the keys
    for(let i = 0; i < Object.keys(json).length; i++){
        let keys = Object.keys(json);
        let obj = json[keys[i]];
        
        // if this obj has the key
        if(Object.keys(obj).includes(key)){
            obj[key] = value;
        }
    }
    return json;
}

// example
setValue(validationSteps ,"fname","this is name");
```

Result will looks like:

```
{
    "0": {
        "location": null,
        "duration": null,
        "membershipType": null
    },
    "1": {
        "fname": "this is name"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found out about this solution similar to yours, before I read your answer. Here's my code https://pastebin.com/H4A6r8FS Could you take a look at it, to see if it's fine, or that it needs improvement? Furthermore it works exactly like your code!

Comment: I also added that setValue method within my form input event listener. So that it gets triggered on the input you're filling in.

Comment: It look shorter than my old ones, but there has one thing you need to check. `for(key in Object.keys(validationSteps))` this loop will get not only your object items but also get the properties. For example, if you or someone add property to `Object`. It may cause some error.You can run the code below and you will see the result in console.

Comment: `Object.prototype.a = "custom prototype";`

`for(key in Object.keys(validationSteps)){
    console.log(key);
}`

Comment: Ah okay, I like your way. Btw in my example you saw some pre-defined values. I did that because those radios are always checked when the page load. Is that a correct way of doing that? Cause they'll only change when `input` listener has been triggered

Comment: I think it's fine, looks like your object is for validation. So you need a default value. If user does not change radios, you still have the default value to use and do not need to do anything in your code.

Comment: Yeah it also saves me some load events where I fill the object with data.